# Is it possible to express disjunction through conjunction and implication?

Tags: boolean-algebra

This question is about Boolean functions. Is it possible to express disjunction $x\lor y$ through conjunction $x\land y$ (or simply $xy$) and implication $x\to y$?

Comment: It should, since negation is expressable with implications

Comment: @miraunpajaro Negation expressable with implications? How?

Comment: I seem to remember implication and conjunction was functionally complete, I can't figure it out now though

Comment: Implication and conjunction are not functionally complete since they both map 1 (truth) into 1. Negation is expressible though implication as $x\to 0$, but one needs falsehood for this. The formula in the accepted answer just slipped my mind.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes - in fact, disjunction is expressible via implication alone:
$$
x \lor y \equiv (x \to y) \to y
$$